# Are static methods good for scalability?

Tags: java, performance, scalability, static-methods

Does static methods and class are good for scalability ? I think so static class/method improves scalability of application and instance methods doesn't scales much. So is it good programming practice to write static method where ever it is possible ?

Comment: What makes you think static methods improve scalability or that instance methods do not scale well?

Comment: Anything which is stateless scales well. So if util class contains all static methods with no static state, then its scales well. I might be wrong. Love to be corrected.

Comment: I don't think the question should have been downvoted.  I was concerned about memory usage of instance methods when I first learned OO/Java and remember searching a lot on that very issue - and the OP's response to my answer seems like it's a similar concern here behind the question.  (Even if not, there are other good answers here on static vs. instance methods.)

Comment: @Anon: I agree with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on *WHY* the method is static.  If it's static because it truly does not need context, then it will probably scale very well compared to something of similar complexity that is not static because it requires context.

However, if it is static merely because you cannot retain the needed context and must still pass it in, or because of some artificial goal of having more static methods, then I would suspect that it will actually scale LESS than the comparable method as non-static.

In fact I think that ASP Classic proved this point.

Comment: @RBarry Young: Here I assumes that static method doesn't have any context and that's the only reason to think that static method scales well.

Comment: Neither *has*, nor *needs* context (there is a difference between those two things).  For instance, a SIN() neither has nor needs context, ought to scale as well as anything.  On the other hand, file manipulation typically *has* and *needs* a context (the file in question), implementing it without any context (by using a file handle or channel number, as we had to before OO) will NOT in any way make it scale better and very well could make it scale *worse*.

Answer (score 11):

> Does static methods and class are good
>   for scalability?

One has little to do with the other.

> I think so static class/method
>   improves scalability of application
>   and instance methods doesn't scales
>   much.

Wrong. Why do you think so?

> So is it good programming practice to
>   write static method where ever it is
>   possible?

No. In fact, it is very bad practice because it abandons the maintainability advantages of object-oriented programming.

Comment: why do static methods abandon the maintainability advantages of object-oriented programming??

Comment: @zPesk: well for a start, they are plainly NOT object oriented.

Comment: Because the whole point of OOP is to encapsulate logic with the data it operates on to make objects. Instance fields are the data, instance methods the logic. This allows you to hide implementation details and think about object interaction at a higher, more abstract level. Static methods and fields are basically a way to do procedural (non-OO) programming.

Comment: Why is he wrong? Take time to explain your own points. OP does not know much about OOP yet why even bother asking? Just explain it instead.

Comment: @RabbitBones22: It is impossible to say why OP is wrong when he hasn't given the *reason* for believing that "instance methods doesn't scales much". It's just not true, there's nothing to explain about that.

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems to consider with static methods:

1. You may introduce a bottleneck if your static method has a large critical region. The largest of course is to declare the whole method synchronized. If it can only be executing one at a time then it's a potential issue;
2. Is whatever it's doing still consistent if you're running the same method in different VMs and on different machines? and
3. Any method that relies on static methods has problems with unit testing.

It's not generally considered best practice but static helper methods are common. Too complex and another approach should probably be considered.

Comment: I had not heard #3 before.  Could you elaborate?  -- thnx

Comment: While a single, self-contained static method is very easy to unit test, anything that *uses* it cannot be separated from it. And if all you have a static methods calling each other 5 (or 10, or more...) levels deep, you effectively cannot isolate (and thus test in isolation) parts of the application logic at all.

Answer (score 3):

No static methods don't intrinsically scale better. Infact the programming style (imperative or object oriented) does not really make any difference to scaling whatsoever. There are two major aspects of scaling and what to do to improve scale depends on which we mean:

1 Scaling by number of requests a second handled

This type of scaling is normally about adding more computers to a cluster to improve overall throughput of the system. Increasing scaling is often about initially reducing the amount of shared resources used through the use of caches and then later making the data access split into shards.

2 Data Scaling

This is when the system gets more and more data over time and operations that access the data (search, filtering etc) get slower as the algorithms are more complex than O(1). In this case the normal strategy is to increase the number of read and write points and use parallel algorithms such as Map/Reduce.

But neither of these aspects has anything to do with whether you use static methods or not, just whether multiple requests work on large sets of data or single sources of data.

Answer (score 2):

No.  I think you may be assuming that each instance has its own copy of the method definition, taking up that amount of space for each instance, which is not the case.

Editing to add:

In case you wonder how an instance method can be actually shared between the instances:  It is because each call to an instance method implicity passes a reference to the instance object to the method.  This is generally referred to as the "implicit this"  In other words - when you define or call an instance method with two parameters like myMethod(a, b), you can think of it as actually being myMethod(this, a, b), and Java takes care of the this parameter for you, without your having to explicitly define or pass it.

(This, by the way, is handled differently in Python, where you have to explicitly put the object reference in as the first parameter of an instance method definition, though not in the call.)

For an explanation of what goes on at the Java bytecode level here's a link:
http://www.artima.com/underthehood/invocationP.html
(See stuff around: "The objectref is the implicit this pointer that is passed to any instance method.")

Comment: @Anon: Whatever you thinks is right. I think non static object requires memory allocation for each and every attribute associated with instance. I might be wrong. But just want to know others view about same.

Comment: What you're thinking is correct for instance variables, but it would make no sense for instance methods which are the same for each instance to be copied for each.  All you need is a pointer to the same method.  See the discussion, for instance, in this link:  http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1025601

Comment: (Each instance knows its class, and can get to the shared method that way - so my "all you need is a pointer" may be misleading.  But see the link for a citation about instance methods actually being shared.)

Answer (score 1):

Which form of scalability do you mean? The scalability, that the code is maintainable and extensible in big and small projects? Then using only static-methods hurt. Do you mean performance? If instance-methods are slower (what I don't believe in this generality), then this doesn't mean they don't scale. If they need twice the time as static-methods, they need also twice much time if you call them all 10000 times. Choosing the right algorithms and data-representation decide much more about the scalability of the performance.

At last, if you think static-methods are the way to go, you should not use an object-oriented language like Java. Try C or Pascal or classic Basic-dialects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree:

In the real world, scalability (or the lack thereof) typically springs from appropriateness of one's algorithms and the efficiency of the operations made against data stores (think: good SQL queries).

Things like whether a method is static or not (or the % of methods which are static) generally have nothing to do with the scalability of a system.  You can certainly have a super scalable system which uses no static methods, or super scalable system which uses them exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Voted down. The OP clearly doesn't quite understand OO. An instance method doesn't take up any extra space when an instance object is created. Static methods aren't going to save you anything unless you're also avoiding creating any instances, in which case you're going so far afield from what an OO language was built for that it's sort of pointless discussion.

Comment: "The OP clearly doesn't quite understand OO"

...which is probably why he asked the question

Comment: @Chris Kessel: Instance method doesn't take any extra space but instance variable take space per instance.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't seem the right place for basic OO understanding. There are hordes of sites and books for learning OO. If the OP thinks he needs to use statics (globals) for everything, he clearly needs to stop and learn OO first. I get why he asked the question. I voted it down because StackOverflow seems the wrong venue to learn what he needs to learn.